# how to create animation of sparkling effect for iphone using cocos2d or Quartz core

Tags: animation, iphone-sdk-3.0, core-animation, cocos2d-iphone

I am creating one application in that i want to give background effect like there are number of starts and something like we are in universe and some starts are getting lighted for few seconds then some other starts etc.

I got one open gles animation of Explosion , but I want that kind of effect using quartz core or Cocos2d so that I can implement other things easily.

if any one do have any idea or any sample for the sample please suggest me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly (that is not quite clear) you can use some particle effect to simulate most of the "cosmic" lighting, starts, comets even galaxy.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/926 , it is particle tutorial